# Python: how to revise tuples in an list?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of x,y tuples.  Think of these original tuples as being a change in x and y.  I wish to apply  these subsequent changes in x and y to the previous tuple.  For ex, after the zero term, x gained 100 and y stayed the same.  Thus the new first term would be (100,100).  After that, x stayed the same and y decreased by 100.  Applying that to the revised first term would result in a revised second term of (100,0) and etc.

```
xy = [(0,100), (100,0), (0,-100), (-100,0)]
```

This is the desired result:

```
xy = [(0,100), (100,100), (100,0), (0,0)]
```

How to work around the immutabilty of lists?  How do I get this done in a loop?

Comment: Lists are not immutable. You probably meant the tuples..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list itself is still mutable; just replace the tuples with new ones:

```
x, y = 0, 0
for i, (dx, dy) in enumerate(xy):
    x += dx
    y += dy
    xy[i] = (x, y)
```

Demo:

```
>>> xy = [(0, 100), (100, 0), (0, -100), (-100, 0)]
>>> x, y = 0, 0
>>> for i, (dx, dy) in enumerate(xy):
...     x += dx
...     y += dy
...     xy[i] = (x, y)
... 
>>> xy
[(0, 100), (100, 100), (100, 0), (0, 0)]
```

Comment: Thank you for making the abyss not as deep.